# Using Gnu/Linux laptop as extended screen from a MS-Windows PC

Tags: linux-mint, windows, multi-monitor, monitors

I'd like to use my Linux Mint (Debian based) laptop as a second monitor for my MS-Windows 8.1 PC. I know how to extend the Windows display over to another screen. When connecting the VGA cable from the MS-Windows PC to the laptop, the laptop screen keeps flickering the Linux OS screen. I can also use the HDMI port if I need to. Does anyone know how to fix this so the laptop screen is an extended screen of the MS-Windows 8.1 PC?

Windows PC specs:
CPU: AMD Phenom II X2 555
RAM: 4gb of DDR3
GPU: ATI Radeon HD 4550

Linux Laptop Specs:
CPU: Intel Core i3-2350M
RAM: 4gb of DDR3
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 3000
Screen: 1366x768 (16:9 Aspect Ratio)
Video I/O: VGA and HDMI
Laptop: Samsing np300e4c-a02us

Comment: why do you believe that the laptop has a VGA input connector?

Comment: There is a big "and" chain in your question, making it hard to read. I was going to fix it, but could not decide what the meaning is. "When connecting the VGA cable from the MS-Windows PC to the laptop, the laptop screen keeps flickering and is still letting me use the Linux OS, and not using the Windows extended screen."

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to use a laptop's monitor as a second monitor for another laptop?

Comment: @cipricus, I have done that before from MS-Windows 10 to MS-Windows 10

Comment: @jsotola, is VGA on a laptop typically one way? To my knowledge, it's two way but I could be wrong. I am an amateur to computer I/O

Comment: Laptop VGA usually (most commonly) it's only out.

Comment: @cipricus it used to be possible to use a PowerBook 145b as a keyboard/trackball for a Mac SE/30 because of how ADB worked. If graphics subsystems used the same kind of architecture (they don't) it would be a reasonable thing to try

Comment: @cipricus, let me try the HDMI port to see if that works, cause I do know this laptop's HDMI is two way

Comment: When you say flickering. Showing Gnu/Linux **and what else?**

Comment: This seems to be a hardware question about MS-Windows. If extending an X11 display on Gnu/Linux, to MS-Windows then their are software solutions. You could see if MS-windows can extend to VNC or RDP. But here would not be the best place to ask.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, goes black for a milisecond or two, then back to the gnu/linux for a handful of seconds. and how would I know what type of display the laptop is?

Comment: If you are doing it via hardware, then it matters not what OS is running with the monitor. So I will be voting to close. Try super user sub-site. (also see earlier comment on VNC and RDP, it may give you a lead).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is a hardware question about MS-Windows.

Comment: A linux-solution might be just to use a software that can display HDMI input (no experience at my end).

Answer (score 1):

Unless explicitly designed to do so, display connections on a laptop are only meant to send signals *to* a monitor, not accept incoming signals *from* another computer.

In short, you very likely cannot do what you try to do just using a cable.

You may want to purchase a Linux compatible HDMI recorder that allows you to have the Linux box just render what it receives from the recorder, and then use that as a second HDMI monitor.